# Create Attributes and Attributesets using AVS-FastSimpleImport

Tags: magento-1.9, php, avs-fastsimpleimport

Is there a way to create Attributes and AttributeSets for products using the Avs FastSimpleImport module?

I want to use an empty shop and need to import (and update) products which almost all of them have different attributes and attribute sets.

So is there any option to do this with the FastSimpleImport module? Or is there any other importer capable of creating them on the fly?